# TINYINT column values switch to true and 1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, tinyint

I have been facing this weird issue where a table column is TINYINT. When I query the table on my local I get records with column values as true or false. I put code on production and it gets true or false values sometimes. But all of a sudden the values switch from true or false to either 0 or 1. I am not sure why this happens. Any insight on this issue would be great.

**Please note that my TINYINT column has values that are either 1 or 0 only.**

So there is this hash I am creating from the records wherein against every key I am storing the corresponding TINYINT column values, which looks like:

```
@content_map: {1=>true, 338=>true, 375=>false}
```

On local the hash looks like above.

On production the hash looks like:

```
@content_map: {1=>true, 338=>true, 375=>false}
```

and sometimes after few reloads like:

```
@content_map: {1=>0, 338=>1, 375=>0}
```

So the hash values keep changing on production, this is what I don't understand. It should either always be true or it should always be 1.

How I am creating the @cotent_map:

```
@content_map = Hash.new
```

Here is a select query on the table with column free of type TINYINT

```
@list = Action.all.select("id, free")

@list.map {|i| @content_map[i.id] = i.free}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving that `@content_map`?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not have boolean data type. It uses tinyint instead. There is no way it uses t or f for that type.

```
mysql> create table foo( boolboa BOOLEAN DEFAULT false );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,26 sec)

mysql> describe foo;
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| boolboa | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values(true);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,05 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values('4');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,05 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values(4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+---------+
| boolboa |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       4 |
|       4 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

From MySQL documentation.

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are *synonyms* for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true:

And more crazy parts

```
mysql> select * from foo where boolboa = true;
+---------+
| boolboa |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from foo where boolboa != false;
+---------+
| boolboa |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       4 |
|       4 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select not false is true;
+-------------------+
| not false is true |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+

mysql> select (not false is true) = true;
+----------------------------+
| (not false is true) = true |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
```

Before I run the query below I was afraid of that MySQL will return "90% 1, 10% 0". Thanksgod, it didn't -))

```
mysql> select true != false;
+---------------+
| true != false |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

**CONCLUSION:**

MySQL engine itself even does not know what is true, what is not false, what should be considered as nonzero, what does nonzero mean etc.. So do not expect much consistency on that issue -))

Comment: This is technically true, but Rails abstracts this away for you. If you declare a model attribute as `boolean`, Rails will store it as a `tinyint` but give you a `boolean` in your code.